# spooling specific records in file using Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to spool 2 records from and oracle data base on the basis of a condition. SO this means I have 1000 records with fields name, address, SIN no and language (english or french). I want to spool 2 records 1 english and 1 french. Is there any way to pick up 2 records at random in which one record is english language and one record is french record

Comment: Please make another attempt at this question, as I have no clue as to what you are asking.  If you want to spool the output of a query to a file, you can use SQL plus and the "spool" command.  If you want to write the output of a query from PL/SQL, you can use the UTL_FILE package.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this one will do:

```
select rownum, lang, name from t where lang = 'french'
union all 
select rownum, lang, name from t where lang = 'english'
order by 1,2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea80b/2)

Comment: I very much agree to your answer... just wondered was it possible without the use of union all...